# Handle Application closing event without Dispose event handler

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I'd like to know if there is a possible way to handle a closing application in Visual Studio 2008 without using the dispose event handler.

If my application crashes or if I close it while it is running:

`Private Sub Foo_Disposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed`

Is not called.

This result in a serious problem, because I'm currently working on multiple Excel files and they remain open after the application crashes or I close it while it's running.

Is there a way to handle this kind of closing application event?

Comment: If your application crashes due to a CLR exception you can use the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception), but for more serious crashes there isn't much you can do. However, in a normal situation where your application is just closing you can subscribe to the [`Shutdown` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.shutdown).

Comment: I mean a crash without any exception. It's all wrapped inside a try catch, but sometimes it just stop working for no reason, i bet is because I'm working with a very low budget rig and old hardware

Comment: Have you tried handling: [Application.​Thread​Exception   Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception) and [App​Domain.​Unhandled​Exception   Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception)

Comment: Il give it a try

Comment: @VisualVincent It sais: _Impossible to find shutdown event_

Comment: _"I mean a crash without any exception"_ - Well, one option would be to create another application which keeps track of your main app. If your application crashes the other app closes the excel documents. The tricky part is to pass the information necessary for the other app to be able to close them.

Comment: _"Impossible to find shutdown event"_ - See the **Remarks** section of the documentation article I linked to. It tells you how you can subscribe to the event (though as I said this will only work for normal, no-crash cases).

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks alot! it works fine :) If you just want to delete the comment and post it as an answer I will be glad to mark it

Comment: But my solution doesn't cover crashes...?

Comment: I think that it's the best way to go at the moment, with random crash I'll make further investigations and I will try to solve the problem instead of handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal situation when your application is simply closing you can subscribe to the [`MyApplication.Shutdown` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.shutdown) and close your excel documents in there.

Subscribing to the event can be done through these steps:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Properties`.
2. Go to the `Application` pane and press `View Application Events`.
3. In the file that was opened, either write the event handler on your own or let VS do it by first selecting `(MyApplication Events)` in the left combo box above the text editor, then selecting `Shutdown` in the right combo box.

Now you should have an event handler that looks something like the one below. Just go ahead and do your cleanup in there:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
    'Do your cleanup here...
End Sub
```

For application crashes caused by CLR exceptions you can use the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception), but for more serious crashes there isn't very much you can do.

A workaround would be to create another application which monitors your main app. When the other app senses that your main application's process has been terminated, it will close the excel documents. The tricky part with this solution is passing the information necessary for the other app to close the documents.

Comment: chiky tricky! thanks for the answer. Appreciate it!
P.S. <3 doom :D

Comment: I'm going to post another question, can you help me with the new one?

Comment: @Simo : DOOM is love, DOOM is life <3. _"can you help me with the new one?"_ - Perhaps, depends on what it's about. :)

Comment: Still some issue in vb.net